# Where search query with method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this little method in my model:

```
def date
    created_at.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
end
```

Now i would like to perform a search query with the help of this method:

```
  @ebm_entry = @patient.ebm_entries.find(params[:id])
  @ebm_entries = @patient.ebm_entries.where(date: @ebm_entry.date)
```

But somehow the `.where(date: @ebm_entry.date)` clausel wont work, i get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: FEHLER:  Spalte ebm_entries
.date existiert nicht
LINE 1: ...tries"  WHERE "ebm_entries"."patient_id" = $1 AND "ebm_entri...
```

What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: It looks like from the error, that `date` column doesn't exist in the table. Can you provide your table schema.

Comment: @saurabh Yes correct it does not exist! `Date` is a method in my model! I thought this is a virtaul attribute?

Comment: so your problems is solved now, right?

Comment: No its not fixed! My question is how i can i find entries by a virtual attribute! Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For querying in this fashion, you can write a scope in the corresponding active-record model like this:

```
scope :dated,   lambda { |date| where(:created_at => date) }
```

Using this, you can query in following way:

```
@ebm_entries = @patient.ebm_entries.dated(@ebm_entry.date)
```

`Scope` adds a class method for retrieving and querying objects. A scope represents a narrowing of a database query, such as in this case `where(:created_at => date)`.

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) is more detail in scope and its usage from rubyonrails page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no such thing as "searching by virtual attribute" :) You can only search real database data.

You can pass a Date object, though, and activerecord will automatically convert it to database date field.

So it would be quite simple to achieve what you want :

```
@ebm_entry = @patient.ebm_entries.find(params[:id])
@ebm_entries = @patient.ebm_entries.where(created_at: @ebm_entry.created_at)
```

And indeed, the formatting thing should be a view thing, not related to data in database.